# DataStax with Azul Zing JVM

Tags: java, datastax, azul-zing

I am currently investigating the use of Apache Cassandra using the Azul Zing JVM and looking for a vendor that could provide support. Does anyone know if DataStax supports the Azul Zing JVM?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Azul are a partner and Datastax do periodically test with Zing.  I know there are customers running with Zing - so I would assume that it's an option.

Definitely worth talking to one of the Sales team.